# Set a group of controls visible with one line of code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, visible

Is it possible to clump a group of controls together and be able to set it visible with one line rather than having to do each individual control's .visible property?  I know it doesn't hurt anything but would like to keep it looking neat and not clump up a function with a page full of .visible control calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group your controls in a `List(Of Control)` or an array and set the `Visible` property using either the `ForEach`-method or a simple `For Each`-loop.

e.g.:

```
Dim toToggle = {OkButton, CancelButton, ControlPanel, SelectionComboBox}
For Each ctrl in toToggle
    ctrl.Visible = False
Next
```

or

```
Dim toToggle = {OkButton, CancelButton, ControlPanel}.ToList()
toToggle.ForEach(Sub(c) c.Visible = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Dominic's solution. Another approach (and this depends on how your Winform is laid out) would be to group the controls into a panel:

```
For Each ctrl as Control in MyPanel.Controls
    c.Visible = False
Next
```

Really all this approach does is keeps you from having to create a new list, but maybe that would be better so you can choose precisely which controls to add.

Comment: If all controls where on the same `Panel`, you could just hide the `Panel` instead of setting the visibility of each single control.